# What is the worst-case time complexity of reflect.DeepEqual() in Go?

Tags: go, time, reflection

I tried to analyze [the source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.1:src/reflect/deepequal.go;l=228), but many other functions are called from within `deepValueEqual()`, and I must admit that the use of recursion is throwing me off in this case.

Is there any official documentation of the function's worst-case running time?

*Edit: I don't quite understand how I would define input sizes in this case with two `interface{}` type arguments and it's adding to my confusion. Perhaps this is due to my unfamiliarity with time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the worst-case time complexity of reflect.DeepEqual() in Go?

O(n).

Note that your question doesn't make much sense formally. "time complexity" is a function of "input size" and how you measure "input size" is not well defined. reflect.DeepEqual takes just one argument so its time complexity is O(1) simply because you cannot apply this function to more than one argument. How you measure the size of *one* argument you didn't tell.

> Is there any official documentation of the function's worst-case running time?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had omitted input size as I was unsure how I would define such a thing for `interface{}` types. I suppose that explains the confusion and downvotes. I don't quite understand the O(n) and O(1) times you mention in your answer. To me, it looks like `reflect.DeepEqual()` takes two arguments -- the types that are compared.

Comment: Two arguments or one doesn't make any difference as both (actually any constant) are in O(1).

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for the clarification. If O(n) is the worst-case, what does the O(1) time represent? The best-case?

Comment: O(n) doesn't mean "worst-case": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation . You might want to clearify what you actually want to know and why you want to know this. The "time complexity" of reflect.DeepEqual for the normal use of the word "time complexity" is pretty uninteresting (for normal uses of DeepEqual).

Comment: Essentially, I have a function that checks if two slices are equal by comparing respective elements using  reflect.DeepEqual() in a loop (given that both slices are the same length). I want to know the time-complexity of such a function. The loop dependent on slice length would be in O(n) time, but I'm unsure of how reflect.DeepEqual() would affect it.

Comment: Okay. Let n = min(len(slice1), len(slice2)). The worst case time complexity of comparing these two slices with reflect.DeepEqual is O(n).

Comment: How could this be extended to things like structs? I'd assume it is still O(n), with n being the min number of fields. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: This _only_ depends on _your_ definition of "problem size". If you include the "size of a struct" and this is m then the running time is O(n*m) which is O(n) as m is a constant. Your question doesn't make much sense for the traditional definition of time complexity.

Comment: Alright then, I suppose my question does not make much sense. I'll try to figure this one out myself. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Just one more remark which maybe clear up the missunderstanding: Suppose you compare two slices both of the the same length n containing strings all of length m. Then the worst case is O(n*m) because the first difference can be in the last byte of the last element.